# How to add thickness to an object?

Tags: modeling

I am converting a map to 3D.

I have succeeded in getting the elevation, but I am unable to add thickness to the data as shown below.

I would like to add thickness to the terrain data as shown in the [video 5:26](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mj7Z1P2hUWk), but the procedure is not clear from the video alone.

If you know how to do this, could you please tell me the procedure?

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's hard to understand what you show

Comment: Enter edit mode, select all _(A)_, extrude "down" on the Z-axis _(E + Z + Z(again) + move mouse "down")_, scale the bottom "flat" _(S + Z + zero)_, recalculate normals outside _(Select all again (A) then press Shift + N)_.